# javascript to protect text line to be removed?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that can do the following thing

1. First it will see if the line in html/text exist or not. if yes than do nothing and if its not there than
2. Than it will remove all attributes in `<style></style>` Tag

**is it possible ?**

If Yes, than how? I am not good in javascript.

Here is what i tried

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
<style>
body{
color:#fff;
background:#000;
}
</style>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    var str="My copyright text"
    var n=str.search("My copyright text");
    //n = 0 or -1
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">my Copyright text</div>
</body>
```

So what this code will do is it will give me 0 or -1 if it will find my text in var str="" it will return 0 and if it will be changed it will return me -1.

What i want todo is first i want to make var str="" from a div id so it it will take the text from div id and will put it in var str and than the code will see the values of 0 or .1 if its -1 than it will remove everything from `<style></style>` tag

**Hi guys I am editing this question because i have a new problem**

i have the following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 #footer{
  border:1px solid;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
<body>

<p id="footer">Copyright google.com and yahoo.com</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var str=document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML;
    var n=str.search("Copyright google.com and yahoo.com");
    if(n == -1)
    {
        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]; // this will get the first which should be the style tag in the head element, if you have others you may need to modify
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code protects my text to be removed or changed but i want to put my link in text if put my links i.e is HTML source my code donot recognize my links and anyone can just remove the link any idea ?

Comment: People will be more willing to help you if you show an effort of trying to solve the problem yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: An error has occurred in my brain while processing your question.

Comment: but why you guys just thumbs down the question if you cannot answer thats so wiered and rude to me

Comment: Personally I haven't thumbs downed the question. I'm just trying to help you learn. Just edit your question and add some code that you've tried. Then people will answer your question and not thumbs down you.

Comment: a thumbs down is to denote a problem with the question. there are 2 problems, your question is very difficult to understand what it is your asking, and 2 you seem to have made no effort to do it yourself, just ask us to do it for you. we find this rude

Comment: ok just pasting my code here

Comment: I still don't understand the question, are you searching the contents of the div or the html including the div tag itself. When you say you want to remove everything from the style tag do you mean a style tag that is inserted in the page like your script tag above (<style>.....</style>) or do you mean the style attribute on the div you are searching e.g. <div style"...">

Comment: w8 a sec simon i am going to put a whole model here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is how to remove the style tag all together if the given string matchs the contents of the div:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var str=document.getElementById( <div id> ).innerHTML;
    var n=str.search("My copyright text");

    if(n == 0)
    {
        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]; // this will get the first which should be the style tag in the head element, if you have others you may need to modify
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are near simon but if i want to remove the style from style tag look above again its a general style tag in head section for whole html page